# Spring Security custom authentication filter using Java Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to configure Spring Security using Java config in a basic web application to authenticate against an external web service using an encrypted token provided in a URL request parameter.

I would like (I think) to have a security filter that intercepts requests from the Login Portal (they all go to /authenticate), the filter will use an AuthenticationProvider to process the bussiness logic of the authentication process.

Login Portal --> Redirect '\authenticate' (+ Token) --> Authenticate Token back to Login Portal (WS) --> If success get roles and setup user.

I have created a filter..

```
@Component
public final class OEWebTokenFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
             OEToken token = extractToken(request);
             // dump token into security context (for authentication-provider to pick up)
             SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);
        }
    }   
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

An AuthenticationProvider...

```
@Component
public final class OEWebTokenAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Autowired
    private WebTokenService webTokenService;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(final Class<?> authentication) {
        return OEWebToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) {
         if (!(authentication instanceof OEWebToken)) {
             throw new AuthenticationServiceException("expecting a OEWebToken, got " + authentication);
        }

        try {
            // validate token locally
            OEWebToken token = (OEWebToken) authentication;
            checkAccessToken(token);

            // validate token remotely
            webTokenService.validateToken(token);

            // obtain user info from the token
            User userFromToken = webTokenService.obtainUserInfo(token);

            // obtain the user from the db
            User userFromDB = userDao.findByUserName(userFromToken.getUsername());

            // validate the user status
            checkUserStatus(userFromDB);

            // update ncss db with values from OE
            updateUserInDb(userFromToken, userFromDB);

            // determine access rights
            List<GrantedAuthority> roles = determineRoles(userFromDB);

            // put account into security context (for controllers to use)
            return new AuthenticatedAccount(userFromDB, roles);
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {
             // stop non-AuthenticationExceptions. otherwise full stacktraces returned to the requester
             throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Internal error occurred");
        }
    }
```

And my Spring Security Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    OESettings oeSettings;

    @Bean(name="oeAuthenticationService")
    public AuthenticationService oeAuthenticationService() throws AuthenticationServiceException {
        return new AuthenticationServiceImpl(new OEAuthenticationServiceImpl(), oeSettings.getAuthenticateUrl(), oeSettings.getApplicationKey());
    }

    @Autowired
    private OEWebTokenFilter tokenFilter;

    @Autowired
    private OEWebTokenAuthenticationProvider tokenAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    private OEWebTokenEntryPoint tokenEntryPoint;

    @Bean(name="authenticationManager")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)  throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(tokenAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean () {  
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();     
        registrationBean.setFilter(tokenFilter);    
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/authenticate**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
            .antMatchers("/home**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
            .antMatchers("/personSearch**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
            // Spring Boot actuator endpoints
            .antMatchers("/autoconfig**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/beans**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/configprops**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/dump**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/env**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/health**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/info**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/mappings**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/metrics**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/trace**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
            .and()
                .addFilterBefore(tokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authenticationProvider(tokenAuthenticationProvider)
                .antMatcher("/authenticate/**")
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(tokenEntryPoint)
            .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl(oeSettings.getUrl());
    }
}
```

My problem is the configuration of the filter in my SpringConfig class. I want the filter to only come into effect when the request is for the /authenticate URL, I've added .antMatcher("/authenticate/**") to the filter configuration.

```
.and()
                .addFilterBefore(tokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authenticationProvider(tokenAuthenticationProvider)
                .antMatcher("/authenticate/**")
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(tokenEntryPoint)
```

When I have this line in all other URLs are no longer secured, I can manually navigate to /home without authenticating, remove the line and /home is authenticated.

Should I be declaring a filter that is only applicable to a specific URL?

How can I implement this whilst maintaining the security of other URLs?

Answer (score 25):

I've resolved my issue by performing a check on the authentication status in the filter before involking the authentication provider....

Config

```
.and()
    .addFilterBefore(tokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .authenticationProvider(tokenAuthenticationProvider)
    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(tokenEntryPoint)
```

Filter

```
@Override
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    logger.debug(this + "received authentication request from " + request.getRemoteHost() + " to " + request.getLocalName());

    if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
        if (isAuthenticationRequired()) {
            // extract token from header
            OEWebToken token = extractToken(request);

            // dump token into security context (for authentication-provider to pick up)
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);
        } else {
            logger.debug("session already contained valid Authentication - not checking again");
        }
    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

    private boolean isAuthenticationRequired() {
    // apparently filters have to check this themselves.  So make sure they have a proper AuthenticatedAccount in their session.
    Authentication existingAuth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if ((existingAuth == null) || !existingAuth.isAuthenticated()) {
        return true;
    }

    if (!(existingAuth instanceof AuthenticatedAccount)) {
        return true;
    }

    // current session already authenticated
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can You post the code of those classess: `OEWebToken`, `AuthenticatedAccount` and `extractToken(request)` method implementation? I would help me a lot with my rest service. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wans't able to make this work. [this baeldung blog post](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-entry-points) helped me to solve my similar situation