# Spring security global preauthorize rule

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am working on a method for services behind a gateway to communicate easily.

The plan uses the scope in an oauth token that would be used by services running on the same system.

For example. The bellow api method will be available if the oauth token has scopes 'acct' and 'user'. Without changing the annotation, I want it to also be available if the ouath token has the scope 'admin' and is missing either or both scopes 'acct' and 'user'.

```
@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('acct') and #oauth2.hasScope('user')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/scopedtest", produces = "application/json")
public Map<String, String> indexWithScope() {
    return getHashMapResult();
}
```

I want this 'admin' scope to be globally accepted so that service developers would not need to include the admin scope on every api controller they make but would still allow internal services to access the apis of other internal services.

This would work as code that would intercept the call to preauthorize and change the response to be that the caller is authorized if that have the 'admin' scope. The call would act as normal if the oauth token has the scopes that are required from the preauthorize annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## This was solved by adding a voter to the existing list of decision voters.

The first step was to create a custom voter class

```
public class CustomVoter implements AccessDecisionVoter {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(ConfigAttribute attribute) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int vote(Authentication authentication, Object object, Collection collection) {
        //Place your decision code here
        if( check_is_true() ) {
            //grant access
            return ACCESS_GRANTED;
        } else if ( check_is_false() ) {
            //deny access
            return ACCESS_DENIED;
        } else {
            //do not make a choice
            return ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

We now need to add this voter to the list of voters that will make the access decision.

```
@Configuration
public class DecisionVotersConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    MethodInterceptor methodSecurityInterceptor;

    @PostConstruct
    @DependsOn("methodSecurityInterceptor")
    public void modifyAccessDecisionManager() {
        ((AffirmativeBased)((MethodSecurityInterceptor)methodSecurityInterceptor).getAccessDecisionManager()).getDecisionVoters().add(0, new CustomVoter());
    }
}
```

This will add your custom decision voter the list of decision voters. By placing it at index 0 it will be checked first. This will allow the voter to grant access before later checks would deny access. The method in this configuration class will depend on the methodSecurityInterceptor being created which will have the initial list of decision voters.

Answer (score 0):

## using WebSecurity

You are currently using a preauthorize rule on a controller action. The power of method security initially is, to use it on methods **not** directly related to routes, because these can be setup `HttpSecurity` request matchers, often by using the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

This - however - is not really helping you, because spring has a route to permission approach, rather than a permission to route approach. This means, if you have one global role, giving access to everything no matter of specific configuration, than you must configure it to all security definitions, if you are avoiding changing the default configuration.

The only way I see to solve your need, is to hook into springs security filtering process and define an exceptional rule for admin scope. You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27564349/5613927) about how to implement a custom filter, which you place after your oauth2 authentication is extracted to look for admin scope (or different global rules)

## tree roles

this is some logical solution I use for my projects, which gives a role some "parent" role, which implies roles down the current node in the tree. so the root is implicitly granting all roles / scopes you configure. For simplicity, I apply these tree logic on-write, like giving [ROOT_ROLE] results in adding all roles under (tree traverse) or revoking all roles found by depth-first search from node up towards root. The motivation is here, that access control policies are often reflecting a hierarchical structure of users, and gives more freedom to design these personal hierarchy properly using a tree. This pattern solves your problem indirectly, in a scalable way