# Spring Boot/Spring Security Choose Between Multiple Authentication Providers Based On Path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have configured my application as such:

I have two authentication providers (provider1 and provider2) and I want to use them for different endpoints:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/v1").authenticated();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/v2").authenticated();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(provider1);
    auth.authenticationProvider(provider2);
}
```

Right now what happens is if I call `/api/v2` `provider1` gets called and if does not raise an exception or return false then only does `provider2` get called.

```
// In org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager

for (AuthenticationProvider provider : getProviders()) {
        try {
            result = provider.authenticate(authentication);

            if (result != null) {
                copyDetails(authentication, result);
                break;
            }
        }
        ...
        ...
}
```

How can I make so that only `provider2` gets called when I hit `/api/v2`?

Something like this:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/v2")
    .authenticated().authenticationProvider(provider2);
```

(I know there is a `authenticationProvider` on `HttpSecurity`, however, that is the exact same as calling `AuthenticationManagerBuilder#authenticationProvider`)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom filter to the Spring Security filter chain that attempts to authorize a request with a custom [Authentication](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) implementation. When you call [AuthenticationManager.authenticate()](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationManager.html#authenticate-org.springframework.security.core.Authentication-), you can pass in an instance of your custom Authentication. Then make sure that you update the supports(Class< ? > authentication) method of your custom provider to accept only your custom authentication class.

You can then apply the custom filter to the security filter chain for specific endpoint using antmatchers.

Comment: Here's an example of a [custom authentication filter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27564349/873590).